# how to write this SQL query with group by in knex?

Tags: sql, node.js, knex.js

How to write this query?
`SELECT referral_code, count(*) FROM users GROUP BY users.referral_code HAVING count(*) > 1`

I spent too much time today on it without any success always getting:

```
Error: error: select "referral_code", count(*) as "cnt" from "users" group by "users"."referral_code" having "cnt" > $1 - column "cnt" does not exist
```

Surely there must be a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you want to use Knex or SQL statment?
in Knex you should use

```
knex('users')
.groupBy('referral_code')     
.having('count', '>', 1)
```

but in sql you have to use Field name in having.
cnt should be delete in the having

Answer (score 1):

You can not use the alias "cnt" in the HAVING clause in this query :

```
select "referral_code", count(*) as "cnt" from "users" group by "users"."referral_code" having "cnt" > $1
```

because the "cnt" alias is not been created when SQL engine processing the HAVING clause, for more details [read this](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2201633&seqNum=3#:%7E:text=Logical%20query%20processing%20is%20the,correct%20understanding%20of%20T%2DSQL.)